# Get key from any values in list

Tags: java, java-8

How to get key from any values in the list for below hashmap?

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

"car"      : ["toyota", "bmw", "honda"]
"fruit"    : ["apple","banana"]
"computer" : ["acer","asus","ibm"]
```

if I pass the value as "ibm", I need to get key as "computer", for "bmw" input need to get key as "car".

I am using below code to get key, need any short or better options

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> {
List<String> list = v;
}
```

Key from List

Comment: `map.forEach((k, v) -> {
      v.forEach(item->{
             
      })
     });`

Comment: I don't get your requirement. what do you expect as result with a specific input?

Comment: value is in List <String>, need to get key for that value

Comment: Add samples of input and desired output. Unclear question for now

Comment: "car"      : ["toyota", "bmw", "honda"]
"fruit"    : ["apple","banana"]
"computer" : ["acer","asus","ibm"]
if I pass the value as "ibm", I need to get key as "computer", for "bmw" input need to get key as "car"

Comment: I think you can better term the question to find out the *_is a_* relationship.

Comment: You need a reverse-lookup map: `"acer"->"computer"` and so on.Build it at the same time as main map, or build it by iterating the main map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for each entry in map check if values contains you keyword

```
String value = "ibm";
Optional<String> key = map.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().contains(value))
            .map(Entry::getKey)
            .findFirst();

System.out.println(key.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to be fancy, you could use [Guava's BiMap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap).

Here's an example taken from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-bimap):

```
@Test
public void givenBiMap_whenQueryByValue_shouldReturnKey() {
    BiMap<String, String> capitalCountryBiMap = HashBiMap.create();
    capitalCountryBiMap.put("New Delhi", "India");
    capitalCountryBiMap.put("Washington, D.C.", "USA");
    capitalCountryBiMap.put("Moscow", "Russia");

    String keyFromBiMap = capitalCountryBiMap.inverse().get("Russia");
    String valueFromBiMap = capitalCountryBiMap.get("Washington, D.C.");

    assertEquals("Moscow", keyFromBiMap);
    assertEquals("USA", valueFromBiMap);
}
```

Comment: at least share an example that matches the OP's question to state why should they use what you suggest.